# why python shell is not displaying Ethiopic characters?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

The codepoint for ethiopic `ዊ` is  `4810`, when I am trying to run the following code on python shell what I got is, `?`. why I am not getting `ዊ` ?

I am testing this on windows 7 and Python 3.7

```
 >>> chr(4810)
```

**output:**

```
?
```

**expected output:**

```
ዊ
```

Comment: Because your terminal doesn't support the font and/or encoding…?

Comment: @deceze my pc supports Unicode, i can write Ethiopic on other apps. why not here?

Comment: What app *isn't* it working in exactly? Standard Windows terminal…?

Comment: yes Standard Windows terminal.